# Problems with intents

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent, package-managers

I have several buttons on my view, each of which that opens other applications.
Calendar, Clock, Calculator etc etc.

I am using the following code to get a list of apps and then I can select which one to run -

```
         final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
         mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
         final List pkgAppsList = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
         startActivity(mainIntent);
```

So I have this method set up for my Calendar button and my Clock button.
I have chosen the clock app for my clock button and I have set it as default.
But when I click on the Calendar button to choose, it automatically opens the clock app.
I've tried this with other buttons, it wont let me choose, instead it opens the clock app, how can I set it up in a different way where I can select the clock app for clock and calendar for calendar?

I have previously asked a question about this and I got an answers and used that method which was above, there is also no tutorials i can find about this either.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to set setComponent() to the intent to specify which app you want to invoke for example,

setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.alarmclock", "com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock")) 

is for alarmclock

else you can use like this,

Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 1):

You need to set setComponent() to the intent to specify which app you want to invoke for example,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.alarmclock", "com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock"));
```

is for alarmclock.

Else you can use like this,

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
startActivity(i);
```

Like this you need to mention what you want to invoke by using the intent.

Comment: how can I find out the other setComponent() ? Like for calculator and others? Also it says I have to add something to the manifest.

Comment: Also I feel that having a chooser is the better way, as there are many users that use different apps for clocks and such. Is there another way?

Comment: You can use Intent.createChooser().

Comment: Is there a way you can save the application chosen from Intent.createChooser() so that the user does not have to keep picking an app?